# "This is a 32 bit computer, you can't use 64 bit software on it"

Tags: opensuse, virtualbox

```
anisha@linux-uitj:~> cat /etc/issue && uname -a
Welcome to openSUSE 11.2 "Emerald" - Kernel \r (\l).

Linux linux-uitj 2.6.31.5-0.1-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2009-10-26 15:49:03 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

anisha@linux-uitj:~>
```

Doesn't this output show that this is a 64 bit machine?

Now when I try to load a `64 bit OpenSUSE 11.3 ISO` on the `VirtualBox`, I get a message as shown in the thread title!

```
anisha@linux-uitj:~/tarBalls> file opensuse-dvd-x86_64.0702..001.iso
opensuse-dvd-x86_64.0702..001.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'openSUSE-DVD-x86_64.0702..001  ' (bootable)

anisha@linux-uitj:~/tarBalls>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have to **recreate** your virtual machine.

Be very careful in [this step](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm) to select a 64-bit "**Operating System Type**", otherwise you will emulate a 32-bit guest machine (on your 64-bit host machine).

You need to recreate the virtual machine because ["changing the type later has no effect on VM settings"](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idp11000016).

Comment: Helpful :) But anyway, I just checked the version of VB install file I have, `VirtualBox-3.2.8-64453-Linux_x86.run `.

Comment: Please, Write an answer to your own question and accept it. It could be useful to other users. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: You don't have to say please. Let me verify it completely and I'll follow up soon.

Answer (score 0):

For 64-bit guests, you need:

1. a 64-bit CPU
2. a CPU capable of hardware virtualisation
3. the 64-bit version of VirtualBox

if any of the points is unfulfilled, you can only run 32-bit guests.

Comment: You can run a [64-bit guest with VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests) as long as you have a 64-bit CPU with virtualization support, even if the host OS is 32-bit.

Comment: Downvoted - blatently wrong as Gilles notes.

Comment: changed "host" to "CPU", thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable virtualization support in the BIOS too...